# Does having the Hi-Jump Copy Ability help with the end of level game?

Tags: kirbys-adventure

I got the Hi-Jump ability near the end of a level, and promptly lost it. But that got me thinking - I often struggle with the end of level "game" - basically, a jump off of a trampoline type thing for points. I never get past the first few floors, so I never get many points.

Does having the Hi-Jump ability make this any easier? Will it help me go higher?

Comment: I don't believe that it does, but it's been a while since I played Kirby, and I don't have a reference to back me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The end-of-level game is based purely on the timing of the button with the base platform. No ability, not even one logically sensible like High Jump, has an impact on this mini-game.